# How To get Signature key for Instagram Auto post API In PHP

Tags: php, post, instagram, instagram-api

Hello I have used https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/ api for post an images to
instagram programatically ,
and this api need signature key to post data to instagram but i can't able to find that key.

does anyone know how i can get that key from instagram developer acccount or anything else ?

i have got 55e91155636eaa89ba5ed619eb4645a4daf1103f2161dbfe6fd94d5ea7716095 key from someone code than image is posed in instagram.
but myquestion is how i can get my own key?

Comment: The link you have provided is not working.

Comment: i have got 55e91155636eaa89ba5ed619eb4645a4daf1103f2161dbfe6fd94d5ea7716095 key from someone code than image is posed in instagram

Comment: but myquestion is how i can get my own key

Comment: @SanjayShiyal Posting via API is currently limited to a small set of partners. It's in closed beta. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

Answer (score 2):

This version of Instagram's API is [deprecated](https://www.instagram.com/developer/).

[image]

Instagram is now a Facebook product and you will find documentation for the new Graph API here: https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

---

For reference, the old documentation is accessible here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/